# Why are some smaller embedded devices unable to run an operating system (and what exactly do they run off of instead)?

Tags: operating-system, embedded, heap-memory, stack-memory

For context, this was taken from an excerpt in a book:
*Finally, sometimes you can't even use heap memory! If you are programming in Rust for a small embedded device, you are going to have to use only stack memory. There's no operating system to ask for heap memory on a small embedded device.*

Coming from someone with limited embedded knowledge, **why are some smaller devices unable to run an operating system.** Surely there are **ultra light-weight operating systems designed for these types of devices?**

If there is no operating system, what exactly does the device then run off of?

I suppose any programs running on an operating-system-absent machine will be unable to utilize the heap and must only resort to the stack (is there a workaround; a dummy heap? [or are we then creating an operating system?])?

If there is a lack of context, then we can close this question (since this is all the information the book provided on 'small embedded device' and 'no operating system'), although to me, the question simply becomes, **at what point is an embedded device considered to no longer be running on an operation system and instead simply following a set of primitive instructions?**

Comment: You need to define the properties of what you call an operating system. Each device runs machine code in the end. It is just an abstract concept to divide all running code in operating system and application. Also, a heap is just a concept. Nobody stops you from implementing a heap and use that, for example as a library, in your applications.

Comment: @thebusybee It was a passage in a book, that phrased it as follows: *Finally, sometimes you can't even use heap memory! If you are programming in Rust for a small embedded device, you are going to have to use only stack memory. There's no operating system to ask for heap memory on a small embedded device.* I am not sure what exactly is meant here with **small embedded device** but I guess it just means a device so small and one-dimensional in what it does, that an operating system (with support for something like a heap) are unnecesary in such a case.

Comment: Well, it does not matter _how_ you organize your needs of dynamic memory, as a stack or as a heap. However, I _love_ these generic statements without justifications. Even on an old 8-bitter like the 8051 I can use the common commercial C compiler system with a heap. Although it does not seem to make sense, since it has just 128 bytes RAM for anything including general purpose registers and stack. -- Well, let us set aside these issues. Please [edit] your question and put the focus on your real problem.

Comment: I disagree that the question is unclear. Very basic stuff for embedded systems programmers perhaps, but still clear and on-topic. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @thebusybee I close it since it does lack context and focus (now turning into other questions). Thanks for your insight either way! I may leave a note to this thread for the author since the book is still in development.

Comment: @Dainank I was halfways through writing an answer when it got closed...

Comment: @Lundin Apologies, I just got the impression I had not phrased a clear question and was worried I was wasting people's time. I have a GitHub profile attatched to this Stackoverflow account. Could you please leave your answer there if the re-open vote fails (use one of the contact ways or some online source)?

Comment: You might want to link to your new more focused question(s) and delete this one after some time. I see at least four embedded questions, as follows. All these need at least rudimentary definitions of "small device", "operating system", and "primitive instructions" to make sense to answer.

Comment: 1) Why are some smaller devices unable to run an operating system? 2) At what point is an embedded device considered to no longer be running on an operation system and instead simply following a set of primitive instructions? 3) If there is no operating system, what exactly does the device then run off of? 4) Will an operating-system-absent machine will be unable to utilize the heap and must only resort to the stack?

Comment: @thebusybee It's ok to ask several questions at once as long as they are related. It might be a bit too big and subjective a topic for SO perhaps - the OP could consider posting on https://software.codidact.com/ instead, which has wider tolerance for "big picture" type of questions. Or for embedded systems questions specifically, https://electrical.codidact.com/.

Comment: Getting back to the part about no heap, it's common for  embedded devices to use one or more fixed block size memory pools. For example a hard drive would have a memory pool of sector sized blocks (4096 bytes + the number of bytes used for error correction), implemented as a linked list queue.

Comment: Note that the use of Rust in embedded systems is by no means common.  Most commonly at the moment it is experimental, academic or being advocated by interested hobbyists.  The commercial embedded market is on the whole rather conservative - no one wants to loose their job by making such a drastic decision.  C++ has struggled to gain acceptance in embedded systems over C, it will take a while before Rust is widely used.  An ISO standard and certified compilers would be a good start. If the subject of the book is Rust rather then embedded it may have a very narrow view of the subject.

Comment: @Clifford Everything seems to indicate that C++ is losing acceptance as well. It was growing steadily in the embedded world until 2011 when the madness begun. I haven't used it for embedded systems since 2007-2008 somewhere and wouldn't even consider it today. I think for a language to take market shares from C, it has to be less bug-prone than C, while at the same time being close to the metal and not affecting performance too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's no operating system to ask for heap memory on a small embedded device.

That is the first fallacy.  While in systems *with* an operating system, it is the operating system that provides that memory on demand, it does not follow that without an operating system you cannot have a heap.  You can and frequently do.  When and whether use of a heap is appropriate in some embedded systems is a different question.  There are issues of non-deterministic timing, fragmentation, failure handling and more that do not lend themselves to mission critical, safety critical or real-time critical applications for example. It is often ill-advised to use a heap (or at least the standard heap accessed through the standard library), but lack of an operating system is not one of them.

> why are some smaller devices unable to run an operating system

Well it depends on your definition of an operating system, but many microcontrollers have only a few tens of kilobytes or less memory. An operating system provides various services perhaps only a small subset of which will be utilised by an application specific embedded system, so it makes sense to only include services that are actually required to minimise footprint.

That said many RTOS (real-time operating systems) are saleable and link only object code referenced by the application.  In that case the RTOS is provided as a regular static link library and the RTOS and the application are a single monolithic linked entity.  That may not meet your or the author's definition of an operating system.  A minimal RTOS provides a thread scheduling kernel and inter-process communication, timing and synchronisation primitives and can scale to a footprint of < 10Kb of ROM, and support a number of threads limited by available RAM and thread stack size requirement.

An RTOS will not typically provide such things you might associate with an OS such as a command shell, application loader, filesystem, networking.  In a small embedded system such components are often independent of the RTOS and can be added as needed from various third-parties in-house developed.  SOme RTOS vendors provide such "middleware" that integrates easily with thier particular kernel.

Embedding a full OS requires much more resource.  A GPOS (General Purpose OS), such as Linux requires in the order of 4Mb ROM and 16Mb RAM for even a minimal system.  Also it will boot in tens of *seconds* rather then tens of *milliseconds* typical of many simpler embedded systems.

> Surely there are ultra light-weight operating systems designed for these types of devices?

Yes - there are many RTOS in various levels of sophistication and scalability, from low end such as uC/OS-III, FreeRTOS, ThreadX and embOS to middle-range such as eCOS, to high end such as VxWorks, OS/9 and QNX.

> If there is no operating system, what exactly does the device then run off of?

Why do you think you need an OS to run code?  An OS after all *is* code.  Embedded systems are application specific software running on application specific hardware.  The application can embed all the necessary hardware support, and all necessary process timing and management within itself.  An operating system may be useful if embedding a COTS (commercial off-the-shelf) board of some standard architecture, but often such support will be provided by the board vendor as an SDK, framework or library rather then a true OS.  For example the Arduino and Mbed frameworks run on a number of off-the-shelf embeddable hardware devices.

> I suppose any programs running on an operating-system-absent machine will be unable to utilize the heap and must only resort to the stack (is there a workaround; a dummy heap? [or are we then creating an operating system?])?

That is as I said not the case.  For example a common C library used in embedded systems is Newlib, it includes a heap implementation, and provides a set of user replaceable stubs known as *syscalls* to map the library to the platform (primarily for memory management and standard I/O).  To support a heap it is only necessary to implement the `_sbrk()` syscall, which ise used to "request" memory for a heap.  That might be implemented as a call to an operating system to get memory, or it can be implemented to simply return a static block to use as heap.  For example the following is a minimal implementation which requires only linker symbols `__heap_start` and `__heap_end` defining the space to be used a a heap to work:

```c
void* _sbrk (int  incr)
{
    extern char __heap_start;//set by linker
    extern char __heap_end;//set by linker

    static char *heap_end;      /* Previous end of heap or 0 if none */
    char        *prev_heap_end;

    if (0 == heap_end) {
        heap_end = &__heap_start;           /* Initialize first time round */
    }

    prev_heap_end  = heap_end;
    heap_end      += incr;
    //check
    if( heap_end < (&__heap_end)) {

    } else {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return (char*)-1;
    }
    return (void *) prev_heap_end;

}
```

> If there is a lack of context, then we can close this question (since this is all the information the book provided

The only lack of context is that you never cited the publication in question.  Name, author, edition, ISBN etc.  It seems that the book may lack authority, but that may be unfair to the author since we have only your brief summary of what the author says.

> at what point is an embedded device considered to no longer be running on an operation system and instead simply following a set of primitive instructions?

Not having an operating system does not necessary imply "primitive".  Although any successful/efficient large application with no formal operating system will likely essentially be its own application specific OS, with a device/hardware abstraction layer, process scheduling, process communication memory management etc as part of the application.